# SAS get the 1st format DATE and NUM attribute from dictionary table

Tags: sql, sas

Good day all,
I need to get the name of the 1st column formatted with DATE and NUM of a list of tables.
I tried something like this in my slq proc and got results, but not the ones i liked.
I think max/min isn't the way...prob have to use the attribute VARNUM of the DICTIONARY table but no idea what approach i can have, anyone can help me? Tks in advance.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select 
   distinct UPCASE(t1.libname) as mylib,
   UPCASE(t1.memname) as mytable,
   max(case when (type='num' and xtype in ('','decimal')) then
      upcase(t1.name) end ) as first_att_num,
   max(case when (substr(format,1,4)='DATE' and xtype in ('date','num')) then
      upcase(t1.name) end ) as first_att_date
from DICTIONARY.COLUMNS t1
right join have t2
   on t2.libname = upcase(t1.libname) 
   and t2.memname = upcase(t1.memname)
group by t1.libname, t1.memname;
quit;
```

Comment: And the have data set contains the names of the datasets of interest, right?

Comment: The data set HAVE just contains the attributes libname and memname on it.

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find `main table LEFT JOIN optional data` much easier to get than `optional data RIGHT JOIN main table`.

Comment: occ i will try to see if any improvement result of that, anyway i normally use left also. Tks for input jarlh!

Comment: To start, remove the join and just use a WHERE clause to select a table. So that you can get your SELECT statement working.  I'm not clear on your intent.  Date variables are numeric.  So is your goal to get the name of the numeric variable in the dataset that is first in position (i.e. lowest VARNUM among the numeric variables)?

Comment: My dataset is dynamic, today i have some tables, tomorrow others, so i need the JOIN clause, i really dont wanna change the code each time the dataset changes, beside they too many. Yes i want to get the name of the numeric variable in the dataset that is first in position (i.e. lowest VARNUM among the numeric variables)

Comment: My query work, just not giving me the 1st num/date formats column as expected. Its giving me the MAX name column with num/date format....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a HAVING clause to restrict to the FIRST, aka MIN(VARNUM), variable.

```
having t1.varnum = min(t1.varnum)
```

If you want to select the variables that have DATE format attached you can use the FMTINFO() function.  This is much easier to do with the output of PROC CONTENTS than it is with DICTIONARY.COLUMNS because PROC CONTENTS puts just the format NAME into the FORMAT variable.  The format Width and Decimal places are stored in separate variables.

```
'date'=fmtinfo(FORMAT,'cat')
```

But the format variable in DICTIONARY.COLUMNS has the complete format specification.  So you will need to remove those extra characters before sending the value to the FMTINFO() function.

```
'date'=fmtinfo(prxchange('s/\d*\.\d*$//',-1,trim(FORMAT)),'cat')
```

So do something like this:

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select a.libname
     , a.memname
     , b.varnum
     , b.name
     , b.format
from have a 
  inner join dictionary.columns b
on a.libname=b.libname
  and a.memname=b.memname
  and 'date'=fmtinfo(prxchange('s/\d*\.\d*$//',-1,trim(b.FORMAT)),'cat')
group by 1,2
having b.varnum = max(b.varnum)
;
quit;
```

If we make the HAVE dataset be the list of all of the dataset in SASHELP then the result is:

```
Obs    libname    memname        varnum    name        format

  1    SASHELP    AIR               1      DATE        MONYY.
  2    SASHELP    BUY               1      DATE        DATE9.
  3    SASHELP    CITIDAY           1      DATE        DATE9.
  4    SASHELP    CITIMON           1      DATE        MONYY7.
  5    SASHELP    CITIQTR           1      DATE        YYQC6.
  6    SASHELP    CITIWK            1      DATE        WEEKDATX16.
  7    SASHELP    CITIYR            1      DATE        YEAR4.
  8    SASHELP    COUNTSERIES       1      Date        DATE9.
  9    SASHELP    FAILURE           4      Day         DOWNAME.
 10    SASHELP    GNGSMP2           9      Date        DATE.
 11    SASHELP    GNP               1      DATE        YYQ.
 12    SASHELP    MDV               7      SHIPDATE    DATE7.
 13    SASHELP    NVST1             1      DATE        DATE9.
 14    SASHELP    NVST2             1      DATE        DATE9.
 15    SASHELP    NVST3             1      DATE        DATE9.
 16    SASHELP    NVST4             1      DATE        DATE9.
 17    SASHELP    NVST5             1      DATE        DATE9.
 18    SASHELP    PRDSAL2          11      MONYR       MONYY.
 19    SASHELP    PRDSAL3          11      DATE        MONYY.
 20    SASHELP    PRDSALE          10      MONTH       MONNAME3.
 21    SASHELP    PRICEDATA         1      date        MONYY.
 22    SASHELP    RENT              1      DATE        DATE9.
 23    SASHELP    RETAIL            2      DATE        YYQ4.
 24    SASHELP    ROCKPIT           1      DATE        DATE9.
 25    SASHELP    SNACKS            5      Date        DATE9.
 26    SASHELP    STEEL             1      DATE        YEAR.
 27    SASHELP    STOCKS            2      Date        DATE.
 28    SASHELP    TOURISM           1      year        YEAR4.
 29    SASHELP    USECON            1      DATE        MONYY.
 30    SASHELP    WORKERS           1      DATE        MONYY5.
```

Comment: Many inputs on your answer, tks Tom.

Comment: Can i have the same ftminfo() for my 1st number columns (type='num' and xtype in ('','decimal'))? Tks in advance.

Comment: "decimal" is neither a SAS format nor a SAS format category.  Are you asking if the display format has zero places to the right of the decimal point?  That is that the values are always displayed as integers?  Perhaps you just want the numeric variables that do not have a date, time or datetime category format attached.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not the most efficient way, you can do this as a series of nested joins: one for Date, and one for numeric. Use min(varnum) to get the first instance of the each value of interest. Note that numbers are always dates, so if you want them to be mutually exclusive, you'll need to specifically state that you want numbers and not dates.

Another thing to note is that this will only catch dates in the `DATEn` format. Any other date formats will be missed unless you specify them.

For this example, we'll use sashelp as our `have` data:

```
proc sql;
    create table have as
        select distinct libname, memname
        from dictionary.members
        where libname='SASHELP'
    ;
quit;
```

Code:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select coalescec(t1.libname, t2.libname) as libname
             , coalescec(t1.memname, t2.memname) as memname
             , t1.name as first_att_num
             , t2.name as first_att_date
        from (select t1_1.libname, t1_1.memname, t1_1.name
              from dictionary.columns as t1_1
                 , have as t1_2
              where    t1_1.libname = t1_2.libname
                   AND t1_1.memname = t1_2.memname
                   AND t1_1.type = 'num'
              group by t1_1.libname, t1_1.memname
              having t1_1.varnum = min(t1_1.varnum)
             ) as t1
        FULL JOIN
             (select t2_1.libname, t2_1.memname, t2_1.name
              from dictionary.columns as t2_1
                 , have as t2_2
              where    t2_1.libname = t2_2.libname
                   AND t2_1.memname = t2_2.memname
                   AND t2_1.format LIKE 'DATE%' 
              group by t2_1.libname, t2_1.memname
              having t2_1.varnum = min(t2_1.varnum)
             ) as t2
        ON     t1.libname = t2.libname
           AND t1.memname = t2.memname
    ;
quit;
```

A more optimized form would be to create the subset table first, then query each type:

```
proc sql;
    create table lookup as
        select t1.libname
             , t1.memname
             , t1.name
             , t1.format
             , t1.type
             , t1.varnum
        from dictionary.columns as t1
        INNER JOIN
             have as t2
        ON     t1.libname = t2.libname
           AND t1.memname = t2.memname
        where    t1.format LIKE 'DATE%'
              OR t1.type = 'num'
        group by t1.libname, t1.memname
        order by libname, memname, varnum
    ;
quit;

proc sql;
    create table want as
        select coalescec(t1.libname, t2.libname) as libname
             , coalescec(t1.memname, t2.memname) as memname
             , t1.name as first_att_num
             , t2.name as first_att_date
        from (select libname, memname, name
              from lookup
              where type = 'num' 
              group by libname, memname
              having varnum = min(varnum)
             ) as t1
        FULL JOIN
             (select libname, memname, name
              from lookup
              where format LIKE 'DATE%'
              group by libname, memname
              having varnum = min(varnum)
             ) as t2
        ON     t1.libname = t2.libname
           AND t1.memname = t2.memname
    ;
quit;
```

```
libname memname    first_att_num    first_att_date
SASHELP AACOMP     lineno   
SASHELP AARFM      lineno   
SASHELP ADSMSG     MSGID    
SASHELP AFMSG      MSGID    
SASHELP AIR        DATE 
SASHELP AIRLINE    DATE 
SASHELP APPLIANC   units_1  
SASHELP ASSCMGR    DEFCREDT 
SASHELP BASEBALL   nAtBat   
SASHELP BEI        X    
...     ...        ...              ...
```

Comment: Tks Stu, i ended using both inputs from Tom and you, but only one can have it, so Tom got it since he was 1st. Tks so much.